# Detect request charset in node js

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook chat has a mechanism which whenever you type English, It automatically detect and display your message LTR, but when any right-to-left character you enter in input box and send it, messages displays in RTL style;

**How Facebook chat, detect input charset? Can I do that with Javascript?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone want to do me a favor and give a down vote, PLEASE write a reason for it AND Please if you do not have any answer or whatever, Don't do me a favor with your negative votes. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, for those who are looking for character's encoding detection in Javascript.
this function could be useful.

```
function detect_message_charset( text ){
    var utfCount = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < text.length; n++) {
        var c = text.charCodeAt(n);
        if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utfCount ++;
            break;
            console.log(" utf-8 character" );
        }
    }

    if ( utfCount > 0 ) {
        return 'utf-8';
    } else {
        return 'iso8859';
    }
}
```